# How to obtain the compilation command in a tool based on libtooling

Tags: clang, llvm, libtooling, compilation-database

I have built a custom tool (based on libtooling) for transforming source code. I used clang's own tutorial and managed to run my own custom FrontendAction. I now need to parse the compile flags that were provided to the tool (on the command line) to customise the transformation. However no matter what I do the CompilationDatabase seems to always return an empty list of compile commands.

This is the sample code:

```c
#include "clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"

static cl::OptionCategory MyToolCategory("CustomTool");
static cl::extrahelp MoreHelp("\nMore help text...");

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    CommonOptionsParser op(argc, argv, MyToolCategory);                     // Parse the command-line arguments
    CompilationDatabase &Compilations = op.getCompilations();

    for (const auto &cmd: Compilations.getAllCompileCommands()) { //<---- this list is always empty!!!
        std::cout << "filename: " << cmd.Filename;
        // Do stuff with compile flags
    }

    ClangTool Tool(Compilations, op.getSourcePathList());           // Create a new Clang Tool instance (a LibTooling environment)
    return Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory<MyASTFrontendAction>().get()); // Run custom Frontendaction
}
```

This is how I invoke the tool:

```sh
./custom-tool sample.c -- -I/some/include/path -std=gnu11
```

I want to be able to get the command line flags `-I/some/include/path` and `-std=gnu11`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Compilation database

Your compilation database (*compile_commands.json*) is either empty or non-existent. All compile commands are technically all of the commands in the database and, thus, empty.

### How does clang then uses the options that I provide

Clang creates an ad-hoc wrapper around the `CompilationDatabase` object that adds those options to whatever file this `CompilationDatabase` has been asked about, even when this file is not in the database itself, and even when it doesn't exist.

### How can I obtain that information then

Instead of iterating compilation commands, you can iterate over the source list and ask (aka `getCompileCommands`) the database to give the commands for that particular file.

### Working demo

```cpp
#include "clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h"

using namespace clang;
using namespace tooling;
using namespace llvm;

static cl::OptionCategory MyToolCategory("CustomTool");
static cl::extrahelp MoreHelp("\nMore help text...");

void print(const std::vector<CompileCommand> &Commands) {
  if (Commands.empty()) {
    return;
  }
  for (auto opt : Commands[0].CommandLine) {
    llvm::errs() << "\t" << opt << "\n";
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  CommonOptionsParser OP(argc, argv,
                         MyToolCategory);
  CompilationDatabase &Compilations = OP.getCompilations();

  for (const auto &File :
       OP.getSourcePathList()) {
    llvm::errs() << "filename: " << File << "\n";
    llvm::errs() << "opts:\n";
    auto Commands = Compilations.getCompileCommands(File);
    print(Commands);
  }

  auto CommandsForFakeFile = Compilations.getCompileCommands("baloney.c");
  llvm::errs() << "fake filename: baloney.c\n";
  print(CommandsForFakeFile);

  return 0;
}
```

The code above generates the following output:

```
> ./myTool test.cpp -- -I/some/include/path -std=gnu11
filename: test.cpp
opts:
    $PATH_TO_MYTOOL_EXEC/clang-tool
    -I/some/include/path
    -std=gnu11
    test.cpp
fake filename: baloney.c
    $PATH_TO_MYTOOL_EXEC/clang-tool
    -I/some/include/path
    -std=gnu11
    baloney.c
```

I hope this information will be useful! Happy hacking with Clang!

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!